# How to require a specific constructor?

Tags: go, interface

I would like to define a interface for serializable objects. In my context serializable means the object can be converted into a string and a string can be converted into an object.

```
type Serializable interface {
    Format() string
    Parse(string) Serializable
}
```

Obviously this is wrong, because this specifies that `Parse` should be a method, although it must be a constructor.

How to require that a type can be constructed in a specific way in Go?

Comment: If you require a specific constructor, it must mean you have implemented that constructor which you are requiring. If you want to encapsulate the type and that constructor, you can put them in their own package. You cannot define the constructor in the interface type.

Comment: You can't. And what you want is already defined by the [`encoding.TextMarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding#TextMarshaler) and [`encoding.TextUnmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding#TextUnmarshaler) interfaces. Instead of requiring a constructor, you may use a method (with poitner receiver) which modifies the object (pointed by the receiver).

Comment: @icza Do I always need two interfaces? It is quite inconvenient to have ReadableValues and WritableValues. I would like to have just Values.

Comment: There is no need for interfaces. Interfaces just provide convenience. You can "merge" them and use one if that makes your code more readable and you happier. Often you only need one side (e.g. just marshaling or just unmarshaling). Using a smaller interface makes testing easier.

Answer (score 1):

Go doesn't have an explicit concept of a constructor, as in there is no nice syntax for constructors. But there is a way to force users of a package to use one of the methods you defined to construct an interface.

To do so you simply include a private method in your interface:

```golang
package mypkg

type Serializable interface {
    Format() string
    serialize()
}

type serializer struct {
    fmt string
}

func (s *serializer) Format() string {
    return s.fmt
}

func (s *serializer) serialize() {}

func Parse(fmt string) Serializable {
    return &serializer{
        fmt: fmt,
    }
}
```

Attempts to implement `Serializable` from outside the package like so:

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/m/example/mypkg"
)

func main() {
    abc := NewAbc()
    abc.Format()
}

type Abc struct {}

func (a *Abc) Format() string {
    return "abc"
}

func (a *Abc) serialize() {}

func NewAbc() mypkg.Serializable {
    return &Abc{}
}
```

Result in a `cannot use &Abc{} (value of type *Abc) as mypkg.Serializable value in return statement: *Abc does not implement mypkg.Serializable (missing method serialize)` error even though `serialize` is defined as a method. Because its not exported the `mypkg` package can't see it so it can't satisfy the interface, thus guaranteeing users will need to use one of the constructors provided.

Answer (score 0):

If I correct understood the question, you can try to use `generics` to parametrize the `Serializable` interface:

```
type Serializable[T any] interface {
    Format() string
    Parse(val string) Serializable[T]
}
```

```
type A struct {
    Val string
}

func (a A) Format() string {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(a)
    return string(b)
}

func (a A) Parse(val string) Serializable[A] {
    var res A
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(val), &res)
    return a
}
```

and then create specific constructor:

```
func NewSerializableA(val string) Serializable[A] {
    return A{Val: val}
}
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/WPrczxHz6_D)</kbd>